# If the composition of 2 maps is open and one of 2 maps is open, then so is the other map.

Tags: functional-analysis

From "Functional analysis" by Walter Rudin, page 39, exercise 9 (and replace "TVS" with "normed vector space").

Suppose

(a) $X$ and $Y$ are normed vector spaces,

(b) $\Lambda \colon X \to Y$ is linear,

(c) $N$ is a closed subspace of X,

(d) $\pi \colon X \to X/N$ is the quotient map, and

(e) $\Lambda x = 0$ for every $x \in N$

Prove that there is a unique $f \colon X/N \to Y$ which satisfies $\Lambda = f \circ \pi$. Prove that this $f$ is linear and that $\Lambda$ is continuous if and only if $f$ is continuous. Also, $\Lambda$ is open if and only if $f$ is open.

Everything is done, only this remains: Prove that $\Lambda$ is open if $f$ is open. My two attempts are:

1. For each open subset $U$ of $X/N$, there exists open subset $U'$ of $X$ such that $U = \pi (U')$. Since $\Lambda$ is open, $\Lambda (U')$ is open in $Y$, which implies that $f(\pi (U')) = f(U)$ is open in Y. Hence $f$ is open.
   What I'm not sure here is the existence of $U'$ above.
2. Suppose that $U$ is an open subset of $X/N$, we have to prove that $f(U)$ is open in $Y$. For each $y_0 \in f(U)$, there exists $\bar{x_0} \in U$ such that $y_0 = f(\bar{x_0})$. Since $U$ is open, there exists $r>0$ such that $B(\bar{x_0},r) \subset U$. The next step is to prove that there is an open ball centered at $y_0$ and is contained in $f(U)$, then $f$ is open. And I got stuck at this step.

What am I supposed to do to complete the proof?

Comment: welcome to Math SE my fellow citizen.

Comment: Hi. From Danang to HCMC with love.
Do you have any idea to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for part 1 of your method: The quotient topology, by definition, is: a set $U$ in $X/N$ is open if and only if $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

However, you can arrive at this same result from the topology generated by quotient norm as well. It suffices to show that $\pi^{-1}(B_r(0))$ is open. But note this set is just $\{ x : \inf_{y \in N} \|x-y\| < r \}$, which can be seem to be open, as it is just the "thickening" of $N$ by $r$ amount.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much for enlightening my mind :)